# Pass Jquery variable through url to php

Tags: php, jquery

Can you pls let me know how can this be achieved

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    id = "user";
 $( '#login' ).html( "<a href = http://localhost/Misc/Receive.php? 
id=+id>Test </a>" );
```

Receive.php
    $val = $_GET['id'];

```
echo($val);
```

want to pass the value stored in variable id to receive.php

Comment: Thank You Suchit. It works now.

Comment: then you can accept the answer by checking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are not proper,change your string to this:

```
$( '#login' ).html( "<a href = http://localhost/Misc/Receive.php?id="+id+">Test </a>" );
```